# Alebgraic confusion with Square Root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

If I define

$y = \frac{\sqrt{g}}{3}$

and $g = x^2$,

does $y$ then become:

$y = \frac{x}{3}$, or

$y = \frac{|x|}{3}$.

I thought the first option is valid, since shouldn't the square root cancel out the square?

Comment: The [principal square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root) of $x$, denoted $\sqrt{x}$, is defined to be the nonnegative square root.  Hence, $\sqrt{(-1)^2} = \sqrt{1} = 1 \neq -1$.

Answer (score 3):

Try it with $x=-5$.  When you square $x$ you get a positive value.  $\sqrt g$ is defined to be positive, so you need the absolute value bars.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that squaring a negative number yields a positive one. So however you slice it, $\sqrt{x^2}$ returns a positive value. Take any negative number to convince yourself.